# Not all code paths return a value with a while loop

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, return, return-value

The compiler is complaining that the following code snippet won't always return. I have inspected it and don't see an issue.

```
private int MyFunction(int b)
{
    int result = -1;

    while (result != 1)
    {
        result = MySmallFunction(out var x);

        if (result == 1)
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
}

private int MySmallFunction(out int x)
{
    x = 1;
    return 1;
}
```

`MySmallFunction` does stuff and returns a code, `1` meaning success, and the rest is an error code.

If it returns `1`, that means that the `out int x` has a value. 
If the return value is not `1` (error code), then I want to retry.

If `MySmallFunction` never returns `1`, the application should just be stuck in a loop forever. That shouldn't be a problem for the compiler.

Comment: The compiler does not know whether the code will enter the `while` loop or not (it never actually will with that condition, but that's another story). You need a `return` after the `while`

Comment: But the compiler will always enter the while loop. I set `result` to `-1` the line before.

Comment: When analysing `MyFunction` compiler *doesn't assume* anything about `MySmallFunction`; since it's possible that, say, `result == -1`, `MyFunction` has nothing to return

Comment: But that doesn't matter, the compiler does not predict what `MySmallFunction` will return at **runtime**. So it has to assume the code can possibly leave the while loop and then needs something to return.

Comment: The compiler doesn't do that kind of deep analysis.

Comment: How many methods deep do you expect the compiler to predict runtime behaviour? The compiler guys could clearly have implemented such a behaviour, but then it may take days to build your app.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you do anything with `b`?

Comment: Let's imagine it **did** let you compile it. Put a breakpoint on `if (result == 1)`. When it hits the breakpoint, set `result` to 5 in the `Immediate Window`. Continue running the code. **What should `MyFunction` return, and why?** _The fact that you (or the runtime!) can't answer the question is one of the reasons why it won't let you._

Comment: The compiler sees that the loop will always trigger, but it doesn't see that the if condition will always trigger, that would require the compiler to loop through your code to know it will always return that way. It still needs a return outside the while for it to be happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the function to this:

```
private int MyFunction()
{
    int result = -1;
    int x = int.MinValue;

    while (result != 1)
    {
        result = MySmallFunction(out x);
    }

    return x;
}

private int MySmallFunction(out int x)
{
    x = 1;
    return 1;
}
```

Now `x` will only be returned if `MySmallFunction` returns a status code of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the signature of the method `MyFunction()` it should return a value to the calling method in all conditions. but in your case, you are returning a value only `if (result == 1)` in all other case it is invalid, so you have to add a return at the end, which will return an integer. So you have to change something like this:

```
private int MyFunction(int b)
{
    int result = -1;

    while (result != 1)
    {
        result = MySmallFunction(out var x);

        if (result == 1)
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But result starts off as `-1`. It is not a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your while loop doesn't trigger, there is not return instruction, you need a return at the bottom of your function outside the while loop.

Comment: But the compiler should see that the loop will always trigger, right?

Comment: The compiler sees that the loop will always trigger, but it doesn't see that the if condition will always trigger, that would require the compiler to loop through your code to know it will always return that way. It still needs a return outside the while for it to be happy